PHP to JSON: How to improve my php script to return a specific json structure?
I would like to convert my PHP script to JSON to return a specific structure with parent and child. I searched some similar questions here, but unfortuntly i didn't find a correct way to solve my doubt:

How to create json array php with childs
php json parse access child values
Php echo json array with children
How to select JSON (dynamic) Parent and Child in PHP?

I have a database table that call tbl_countries that's similar to the structure below:
id | countryID | country | city
-----------------------------------------
 1 |     1     | Greece  | Athens
 2 |     1     | Greece  | Thessalonica
 3 |     2     | Italy   | Rome
 4 |     2     | Italy   | Milan

What i would like to do is convert my php script to return a json structure as below:

    [{
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Greece",
      "children": [{
        "id": "Athens",
        "text": "Athens"
      }, {
        "id": "Thessalonica",
        "text": "Thessalonica"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Italy",
      "children": [{
        "id": "Milan",
        "text": "Milan"
      }, {
        "id": "Rome",
        "text": "Rome"
      }]
    }]


Below is the php script that i'm trying to convert like json structure above. This script, when executed, return information correctly, but not like the structure that i would like to has:

include 'config.php';

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT countryID, country, city FROM tbl_countries'); 
 
$stmt -> execute(); 
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($countryID, $country, $city);

$json = array();

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {

$json[] = array("id" => $countryID, "text" => $country, "children" => [array("id" => $city, "text" => $city)]);

}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r(json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));


In this case how can i improve my php script to return a similar json structure above?

Your table structure seems weird, but I’ll ignore that. I personally like to make simple objects to represent my data, it is easier for me to reason about. Some people say it is overkill though. A quick demo might be something like this: https://3v4l.org/IPQUX

First, i would rename the database table tbl_countries into tbl_cities because that's what they are, and at the json output result of children[]['id'] should be the field id of the table above and not the city name. But this is what I would do.
So, giving your code, this is how I would improve it to give your expected result:
include 'config.php';

$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare('SELECT countryID, country, city FROM tbl_countries'); 
 
$stmt -> execute(); 
$stmt -> store_result(); 
$stmt -> bind_result($countryID, $country, $city);

$json = array();
$countryIdsArr = []; // this would help keeping track of processed countries
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {

    $countryIdx = array_search($countryID, $countryIdsArr);
    if ($countryIdx !== false) { //country row exists
        $json[$countryIdx]['children'][] = ['id' => $city, 'text' => $city]; // insert row into existing children array
    } else {
        $countryIdsArr[] = $countryID; // add the country id
        $json[] = ['id' => $countryID, 'text' => $country, 'children' => [['id' => $city, 'text' => $city]]]; // add the row
    }
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r(json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));


Thanks for the help! I will make some adjustments to my script based on this solution.
